# Is there a simple way to make a geodesic using only modifiers and the modelling interface (No nodes)?

Tags: mesh

Is there a simple (ish) way to make a geodesic dome using only modifiers and the default modeling interface?

My Aim is to have an object similar to an Ico Sphere, but made up of polygons with a greater number of vertex. Such as Hexagons or Octagons.

I'm specifically excluding any methods that involve plugins that don't come with the base download, or the node interface, as these parts of Blender have not yet been introduced to the target audience and using them would create a distraction (For example, people tinkering in the node interface when they should be concentrating on the more basic tools).

I understand that this is an artificial limitation, but please respect it.

I have seen [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70985/link-faces-of-an-icosphere-for-modeling-a-geodesic-dome) solution, but specifically cannot use it, as it requires additional tools that have not yet been introduced, so it does not provide a suitable answer.

Comment: Question already answered [Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167534/hexagon-sphere-wait-with-specified-number-of-hexes)

Comment: Their is an addon called geodesic dome. And I think it comes with blender. https://imgur.com/226M3tT made with the same addon

Comment: Answered here [Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167534/hexagon-sphere-wait-with-specified-number-of-hexes) once I realized what to look for.

Comment: @The Kalaakaar, it looks like my question was answered already, I found the answer once I realized what I needed to search for.

Comment: @The Kalaakaar, yes, I linked to it above and tried to put it down as an answer, but the system won't allow me to for some reason.

Comment: If  @TheKalaakaar 's link actually answers your question, then I feel comfortable closing it as a duplicate, even though the answer is one of mine. If, for _any_ reason it's not satisfactory, please go ahead and edit your post explaining why, and we can re-open for you.